# How to retrieve data from realtime database using indexOn in cloud functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Firebase structure:

```
{
  "config" : [
    {
      "config1" : {
        "hideimage" : true
      }
    },
    {
      "config2" : {
        "hideimage" : false
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Database rules:

```
"config": {
  ".indexOn": ["hideimage"]
}
```

I'm trying to retrieve all config items that have hideimage attribute set to true using:

```
 admin.database().ref('config').orderByChild("hideimage").equalTo(true).once('value', result => {});
```

The expected result should be:

```
[{
  "config1" : {
    "hideimage" : true
  }
}]
```

but I'm retrieving a null response without getting any error.

Answer (score 2):

Your data structure contains two nested levels:

1. you have an array
2. inside the first array element, you have `config1` and `config2`

You can see this if you look at the Firebase console, where your data will show like:

```
{
  "config" : {
    "0": {
      "config1" : {
        "hideimage" : true
      }
    },
    {
      "config2" : {
        "hideimage" : false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Firebase can only query nodes in a flat list, not a tree. So with your current data structure it can only find the node with `hideimage=true` under `/config/0`, **not** under all `/config` children.

Since you're already naming your `config1` and `config2` uniquely, I think the array may be a mistake, and you're really looking for:

```
{
  "config": {
    "config1" : {
      "hideimage" : true
    },
    "config2" : {
      "hideimage" : false
    }
  }
}
```

With this data structure your query will work.